# Windows Service Management Node Won't Start

Tags: mysql, windows, ndbcluster, mysql-cluster

I'm trying to set up a basic Cluster on my Win7 PC for testing. But I am stuck at the first hurdle. I have installed the Management Node as a Service:

`C:\MySQLCluster\ManagementNode1\bin\ndb_mgmd.exe --install --config-file=C:\MySQLCluster\ManagementNode1\config.ini`

But when I try and start the service it instantly stops. Surely as the management node it should run as a service?

What else do I need to do?

I am trying to start it from the Services Window, but I just get

> The MySQL Cluster Management Service on Local Computer Started and then stopped. Some Services Stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs

Alternatively from the command line:

```
NET START ndb_mgmd
```

> The MySQL Cluster Management Server service is starting. 
>   The MySQL Cluster Management Server service could not be started. 
>   The service did not report an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## DISCLAIMER : Not a CMCDBA, Not a MySQL Cluster Expert

According to [**the Book**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328550)

[image: MySQL Clustering]

Page 175 describes `ndb_mgmd` as follows:

> The **ndb_mgmd** binary represents the management server. This program reads in the cluster configuration file (config.ini) and then sends the configuration to any of the later starting nodes.It is also used for management (for example, restarting nodes, starting backups) and monitoring the health of the cluster. It also creates the cluster log, which is a central location for all cluster activities to be logged to.

Just from that brief description, you need to do the following:

- Make sure there are no Storage Nodes and SQL Nodes running before starting `ndb_mgmd`
- You need to locate the cluster log and find any vital error messages
- Check to make sure config.ini has this:

`config.ini`

```
[NDB_MGMD]
id=(some number)
HostName=(DNS Name or IP Address)
```

- Check to make sure `config.ini` can see every other node

Sorry, this is not really an answer. This is what I would do in your situation.

Here are the MySQL Cluster Experts in the DBA StackExchange:

1. [Frazer Clement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4981/frazer-clement)
2. [Mat Keep](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4224/mat-keep)
3. [Andrew Morgan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4223/andrew-morgan)

Until someone can fully address this, I would defer to them to come up with an answer.